# Hideshow minor mode in LaTeX

Tags: latex, hideshow

It seems that HideShow mode is not compatible with LaTeX.
Is there any way to achieve a similar effect: hide some blocks that I highlight?

Answer (score 0):

HideShow has a non-interactive function that hides a region (`hs-hide-comment-region`). I've written a wrapper function to call this function on the current region, if it is active. You can have the region reappear with any of the HideShow "show" commands (e.g. `hs-show-block` while your point is on the hidden region). This command checks if HideShow is enabled in the current buffer, which is necessary to make sure that the hidden region is displayed properly and that the show commands will work properly.

This command should work in any buffer where `hs-minor-mode` is enabled, including ones where the major mode is `LaTeX-mode`.

```
(defun drg-hs-hide-region (beginning end)
  (interactive "r")
  (if hs-minor-mode
      (when (use-region-p)
        (hs-hide-comment-region beginning end)
        (deactivate-mark))
    (message "hs-minor-mode must be enabled for this function to be run.")))
```